# What unit should I use to measure the light intensity of aragos spot

Tags: optics, waves, visible-light, measurements, diffraction

I am trying to measure the relationship with the radius and its effect on the light intensity of Arago's spot. I plan to use a camera or a light meter but I am not sure what unit to use in my investigation. Should I use lux or:

W/sr

cd (lm/sr)

W/m^2

W/(sr m^2)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $W/m^2$ is the best unit, but you can use others , if they are proportional to the intensity.